# I would like to retrieve and display the ordered product name in woocommerce subjet email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

as on title I'm traying to show the ordered product name in woocommerce subject  email. At the moment only {order_number} - {order_date}.
I have tried :  {product_name} and {order_name} but it doesn't worcks
Thanks

Comment: I think you'll need to create a plugin that substitute {product_name} with the correct information when the email is being send

Comment: Your order can contain multiple products, so you can't have it at this level. Or hook yourself to the `woocommerce_email_title` filter and loop through the order products.